# How to set user defined permisiions when creating an excel file(.xlsx) using python or in linux

Tags: python, excel, file-permissions

I wanted to create an excel document with some user defined permission(Read, write, execute) when it is being created using python or through linux/windows terminal. Or is there any way to extract the properties of excel file which contains permissions and change the permission?

Is there any way of creating it?

please find the attached image for reference.

[image]

Any sort of idea would be really helpful.

Comment: Once you've created the file, you can use os.chmod: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: Hi @evamvid Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it is not working for excel documents .

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: it is not giving any error. it is creating the excel file but taking it's own default values. example i gave 0o777 but when i see the file permissions on properties it is giving me 0o664 way.

Comment: in linux, try running it as root. It could be that python is being denied permission to edit the permissions.

Comment: ok will try and see it